# php mysql search for text

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a blog, and i have to post things in series, and i need to link them together.
I want to input the next post id to the previous post.
The challenge now being, is there a way to search using the mysql like expression to check for something like this:
i have a title Mindset 2, which come from mindset 1,
is there a way to search and get mindset 1 from the database, mindset 2?
`$sql = 'SELECT * FROM post WHERE title LIKE "mindset 2"'`;

Because i think the 1 and 2 will be a distraction to the search.
Thanks

Comment: `LIKE` without pattern symbols is `=`.

Answer (score 0):

% - The percent sign represents zero, one, or multiple characters

try this one:

```
'SELECT * FROM post WHERE title LIKE "%mindset 2%"'
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

but anyway, I think it's better instead of fetching just a single post, you fetch the `id` and `title` of the previous and the next post, so you can put a link to them.

Comment: Thanks. but I have only mindset 1 in the database, am trying to match for mindset 1 using mindset 2, will the 2 not be an obstacle.

Comment: 'SELECT * FROM post WHERE title LIKE "%mindset%"' so use this one.

Comment: Thanks @Sam. I figured a better way of doing it by having a previous field linked. With that I don;t need to input any next field. Once I query a post, I get the, I use the ID to query the database if it has a field having it as the previous post, then it becomes the next post.